# Mongoose aggregate to filter data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get the count of this month's data using aggregate but it's giving me no match found even though I have data in DB.

```
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    const start = new Date(year, month, 1).setHours(0, 0, 1);
    const end = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).setHours(23, 59, 59);

        const data = await verificationModel.aggregate([
            {
            $match:{'status':{ $gt: 3, $lt:7},'createdAt': { $gt:start, $lt:end},'fename': { $ne: null }}
            },
            {
            $facet: {
              "categorizedBycasecount": [
                {
                  $unwind: "$fename"
                },
                {
                  $sortByCount: "$fename"
                },
                {$limit:5},
              ]
            }
            }
        ]);
```

created a mongo playground it's working there [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Orga6dtvYNj)

If I remove createdAt filter data is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing is fine except the start and end date

start and end date which you calculated is in string format shown below

```js
var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    const start = new Date(year, month, 1).setHours(0, 0, 1);
    const end = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).setHours(23, 59, 59);

console.log({start, end})
```

You can update the code to get the required format for the mongodb createdAt field

```js
var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    const start = new Date(year, month, 1).setHours(0, 0, 1);
    const end = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).setHours(23, 59, 59);
    console.log(new Date(start).toISOString())
    console.log(new Date(end).toISOString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var month = new Date().getMonth();
 var year = new Date().getFullYear();
 const start = new Date(new Date(year, month, 1).setHours(0, 0, 1));
 const end = new Date(new Date(year, month + 1, 0).setHours(23, 59, 59));
```

this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Date library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). Then is would be simply like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "createdAt": {
            $gt: DateTime.now().startOf('month').toJSDate(),
            $lte: DateTime.now().plus({ months: 1 }).endOf('day').toJSDate()
         }
      }
   },
   { $sortByCount: "$name" },
   { $limit: 5 },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         categorizedBycasecount: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   }
])
```

A `$facet` stage with just one element does not make much sense to me, I would prefer `$group`